# jQuery count up numbers from 0 to div number

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML :

```
<div id="value">300</div>
```

jQuery :

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var start= 0 ;
    var end = 100;
    var duration = 500;
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}

animateValue("value",0,0,0);
```

with this code in up the count up number going from 0 to 100 with 500ms duration !
how can i edit the end var to what numbers are in that div i selected?
i tried this :

`var end = "$('#value').text();"` but this dont work .
hope u will help me to edit this line.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to use `parseInt( getElementById(id).textContent )` to first retrieve the text-content and then change that to a number (as opposed to a string, as `textContent` will always return):

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var start= 0 ;

    // here we retrieve the text of the 'target' element by its 'id',
    // and convert the returned value into a number, using
    // parseInt(); the first argument is the string to convert and
    // the second is the numeric base of the number into which you
    // want to convert the given numeric string:
    var end = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).textContent, 10);
    var duration = 500;
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}

animateValue("value",0,0,0);
```

```js
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    var start= 0 ;
    var end = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).textContent, 10);
    var duration = 500;
    var range = end - start;
    var current = start;
    var increment = end > start? 1 : -1;
    var stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range));
    var obj = document.getElementById(id);
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        current += increment;
        obj.innerHTML = current;
        if (current == end) {
            clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}

animateValue("value",0,0,0);
```

```html
<div id="value">300</div>
```

Note that the above suggestion will cause errors if the `textContent` of the element can't be converted into a nummber; so it may be worth including error-handling to anticipate such failures, for example including a 'default' number should `parseInt()` return `NaN` (Not a Number):

```
// here, if parseInt() returns NaN (an essentially falsey value) then
// the default of 100 will be used instead:
var end = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).textContent, 10) || 100;
```

And with some sanity-checks and tidying up, I'd suggest the following approach:

```
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
    // already declared variables, they don't need
    // re-declaring with 'var' (you declared/defined them
    // in the function's openening parenthesis):

    // Ensuring that we have a defined 'start' value,
    // if there is no start argument (its typeof is equal
    // to 'undefined' we set the default of 0; otherwise
    // if it is defined we set to either the Number that was
    // passed to the function (converting, if necessary, from
    // a String and, if that returns NaN we instead use the
    // default of 0):
    start = 'undefined' === typeof start || !parseInt(start, 10) ? 0 : parseInt(start, 10);

    // here we retrieve the textContent of the element with
    // the id given in the function arguments; convert that
    // into a base-10 number and use that number, unless
    // parseInt() returns NaN, in which case we use the default
    // of 100:
    end = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).textContent, 10) || 100;

    // as above, we need to ensure that duration is defined,
    // check that it's a number (or numeric string) and then
    // use that nummber; otherwise we can simply use the default
    // of 500:
    duration = 'undefined' === typeof duration || !parseInt(duration, 10) ? 500 : parseInt(duration, 10);


    var range = end - start,
        current = start,
        increment = end > start ? 1 : -1,
        stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
        obj = document.getElementById(id),

        timer = setInterval(function () {
            current += increment;
            obj.innerHTML = current;
            if (current == end) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }, stepTime);
}

animateValue("value");
```

```js
function animateValue(id, start, end, duration) {
  // already declared variables, they don't need
  // re-declaring with 'var' (you declared/defined them
  // in the function's openening parenthesis):

  // Ensuring that we have a defined 'start' value,
  // if there is no start argument (its typeof is equal
  // to 'undefined' we set the default of 0; otherwise
  // if it is defined we set to either the Number that was
  // passed to the function (converting, if necessary, from
  // a String and, if that returns NaN we instead use the
  // default of 0):
  start = 'undefined' === typeof start || !parseInt(start, 10) ? 0 : parseInt(start, 10);

  // here we retrieve the textContent of the element with
  // the id given in the function arguments; convert that
  // into a base-10 number and use that number, unless
  // parseInt() returns NaN, in which case we use the default
  // of 100:
  end = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).textContent, 10) || 100;

  // as above, we need to ensure that duration is defined,
  // check that it's a number (or numeric string) and then
  // use that nummber; otherwise we can simply use the default
  // of 500:
  duration = 'undefined' === typeof duration || !parseInt(duration, 10) ? 500 : parseInt(duration, 10);


  var range = end - start,
    current = start,
    increment = end > start ? 1 : -1,
    stepTime = Math.abs(Math.floor(duration / range)),
    obj = document.getElementById(id),

    timer = setInterval(function() {
      current += increment;
      obj.innerHTML = current;
      if (current == end) {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }, stepTime);
}

// using the defaults:
animateValue("value");

// using a custom 'start' (first as a number):
animateValue("value2", 200);
// (and as a string):
animateValue("value3", "500");
```

```html
<div id="value">300</div>

<div id="value2">500</div>

<div id="value3">1000</div>
```

References:

- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent).
- [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Comment: can u tell me is this possible to slow count speed when count up is near to finish ? @David Thomas

Comment: It's certainly possible, yes; but I'd suggest asking it as a new question (and perhaps linking back to this one for context) when you explain your requirements. Obviously, though, please do search for an existing question along the lines of the question you want to ask. It may have been asked already.

Comment: Thanks you very much.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed! I'm glad to have been of some help :)

Comment: Hope u will help me at my next question for duration go slower than start in end . i will post it in 30 mins .